# How to add a ComboBoxAction to a ToolBar in Intellij

Tags: intellij-plugin

I want to add a ComboBox to ToolBar in my Intellij plugins, but I did not find how to achieve it in the official document.

Like this:
[image: Example:]

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed using `ListPopup`. refer to [https://github.com/heyuxian/code-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/me/javaroad/plugins/config/TemplateEditorConfigurable.java#L166](http://Implement%20the%20pop-up%20menu)